# reshaping from long to wide is working only for n!-1 rows

Tags: r

I am working on a function that will take all combinations of column names. I can successfully implement this however I lose a row of combinations. It turns out that `pivot_wider` only works successfully for `n!-1` rows, as opposed to `n!` rows.

Here's a reproducible example of what I am after:

```
perm_lm <- function(data,...){
  #set the arguments
  pr <- list(...) %>% unlist() %>% data.frame(args=.)
  response=pr[1,]
  nm <- names(data)
  #get the predictors
  nm<-nm[!nm %in% response]
  
  #This produces n! rows
  perm_names <- do.call(rbind, permn(length(nm))) %>% data.frame()
  #this produces n!-1 rows
  test<-permute::allPerms(length(nm)) %>% data.frame()
  
  n <- nrow(test)
  nl <- length(nm)
  
 nm_names <- tibble(value = 1:nl,
                     nm_name = nm)
 test  %>% 
    pivot_longer(-c()) %>% 
    inner_join(nm_names, by='value') %>% 
    select(-value) %>% 
    mutate(row=rep(1:n, nl))%>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = nm_name)
  
}
```

This works successfully when I use `test`:

```
perm_lm(teengamb, 'gamble')

    row X1     X2     X3     X4    
  <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1     1 sex    sex    status verbal
2     2 status status status verbal
3     3 income sex    verbal income
4     4 verbal sex    verbal income
5     5 sex    sex    verbal income
6     6 status income income status
```

Alternatively, if I use `perm_names`, I get a list of values at the diagonal and the rest filled with null.

```
    row X1        X2        X3        X4       
  <int> <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>   
1     1 <chr [4]> <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>   
2     2 <NULL>    <chr [4]> <NULL>    <NULL>   
3     3 <NULL>    <NULL>    <chr [4]> <NULL>   
4     4 <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <chr [4]>
5     5 <chr [4]> <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>   
6     6 <NULL>    <chr [4]> <NULL>    <NULL>
```

I know that I can manually enter the last combination which is just `1 2 3 4` in this case, but why does this only work for `n!-1` rows?

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why this happens and it's likely the case of how I am trying to reshape the columns. Instead, I opted to replace the values in the columns when it's in a wide format, rather than re-shaping them. This works much better, as the result from the above produced duplicate names for some reason:

```
perm_lm <- function(data,...){
  #set the arguments
  pr <- list(...) %>% unlist() %>% data.frame(args=.)
  response=pr[1,]
  nm <- names(data)
  #get the predictors
  nm<-nm[!nm %in% response]
  
  #This produces n! rows
  perm_names <- do.call(rbind, permn(length(nm))) %>% data.frame()
  nl <- length(nm)
  nm_names <- matrix(1:nl, ncol=nl, nrow=nl) %>% data.frame() %>% mutate(predictors = nm)
  
  xnm <- head(names(nm_names), n=-1)

  
  perm_names[xnm] <- Map(function(x, y) nm_names$predictors[match(y, x)],
                         nm_names[xnm], perm_names[xnm])
  return(perm_names)
}

ac<-perm_lm(teengamb, 'gamble')
```

output:

```
1    sex status income verbal
2    sex status verbal income
3    sex verbal status income
4 verbal    sex status income
5 verbal    sex income status
6    sex verbal income status
```